# I have a problem in ASP.NET & C#: after I successfully save a record

Tags: c#, asp.net

After I successfully save a record, after reloading the page (<kbd>F5</kbd>) it automatically generates a new record exactly the same as the one I saved earlier!

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Are you passing parameters in the URL, rather than making a POST request?

Answer (score 2):

@KingB9.  When you press F5 you are resubmitting the form with the details of the record and thus, saving it again.  Some browsers may be warning you that you are about to resubmit.

The pattern for this is to redirect the browser to a new location (it can be the same URL as the current URL) but you must redirect to prevent this from occurring.

Have a look at `Response.Redirect`.

Comment: I will try, Thank you very much!!